# Terraform resource creation aws_iam_policy fails due to malformed policy document

Tags: terraform, malformed, aws-iam-policy

I want to create an AWS IAM policy for multiple ECR repos

Terraform module call

```
module "cocos-ecr-all-repo-policy" {
  count      = (data.aws_region.current.name == "eu-central-1" ? 1 : 0)
  source     = "./modules/ecr-policies/ecr-all-repo-policy"
  account_id = data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id
}
```

Module

```
variable "account_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "AWS account id"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "iam-policy" {
  name = "ecr-repo-user-policy"
  description = "IAM policy for ecr users"

  tags = {
    Creator = "terraform"
  }

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version   = "2012-10-17"
    statement = [
      {
        sid       = "EcrRepositoryAccess"
        effect    = "Allow"
        action   = [
          "ecr:DescribeImages",
          "ecr:ListTagsForResource",
          "ecr:ListImages",
          "ecr:PutImage",
          "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
          "ecr:BatchGetImage",
          "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
          "ecr:BatchDeleteImage",
          "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
          "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
          "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
        ]
        resources = [
          "arn:aws:ecr:*:${var.account_id}:repository/repo1/*",
          "arn:aws:ecr:*:${var.account_id}:repository/repo2/*",
        ]
      },
      {
        sid       = "EcrToken"
        effect    = "Allow"
        actions   = [
          "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        ]
        resources = [
          "*",
        ]
      }
    ]
  })

}
```

Plan returns this

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.cocos-ecr-all-repo-policy[0].aws_iam_policy.iam-policy will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_policy" "iam-policy" {
      + arn         = (known after apply)
      + description = "IAM policy for ecr users"
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + name        = "ecr-repo-user-policy"
      + path        = "/"
      + policy      = jsonencode(
            {
              + Statement = [
                  + {
                      + Action    = [
                          + "ecr:DescribeImages",
                          + "ecr:ListTagsForResource",
                          + "ecr:ListImages",
                          + "ecr:PutImage",
                          + "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                          + "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                          + "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                          + "ecr:BatchDeleteImage",
                          + "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                          + "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                          + "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                        ]
                      + Effect    = "Allow"
                      + Resources = [
                          + "arn:aws:ecr:*:<AWS account id>:repository/repo1/*",
                          + "arn:aws:ecr:*:<AWS account id>:repository/repo2/*",
                        ]
                      + Sid       = "EcrRepositoryAccess"
                    },
                  + {
                      + Actions   = [
                          + "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                        ]
                      + Effect    = "Allow"
                      + Resources = [
                          + "*",
                        ]
                      + Sid       = "EcrToken"
                    },
                ]
              + Version   = "2012-10-17"
            }
        )
      + policy_id   = (known after apply)
      + tags        = {
          + "Creator" = "terraform"
        }
      + tags_all    = {
          + "Creator" = "terraform"
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Apply returned error message:

```
Error: error creating IAM policy ecr-repo-user-policy: MalformedPolicyDocument: Syntax errors in policy.
```

Creation of policy with AWS Console GUI works fine.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:ListTagsForResource",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ecr:*:<AWS account id>:repository/repo1/*",
                "arn:aws:ecr:*:<AWS account id>:repository/repo2/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is with first statement to create ECR repo permissions. I tried different changes to terraform code, un/capitalization of key words like Action, add/remove comma after last line of ressource and action blocks. Commenting out second statement did not change anything. Nothing did help. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of syntax errors in your policy doc

All the keys in this policy doc should be in Camelcase and use singular nouns instead of plural, for example, it's `Resource` instead of `resources`. You can also find a short example here at the official doc as well https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_policy

So, Your policy should be like this

```
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version   = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid       = "EcrRepositoryAccess"
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Action   = [
          "ecr:DescribeImages",
          "ecr:ListTagsForResource",
          "ecr:ListImages",
          "ecr:PutImage",
          "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
          "ecr:BatchGetImage",
          "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
          "ecr:BatchDeleteImage",
          "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
          "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
          "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
        ]
        Resource = [
          "arn:aws:ecr:*:<AWS account id>::repository/repo1/*",
          "arn:aws:ecr:*:<AWS account id>::repository/repo2/*",
        ]
      },
      {
        Sid       = "EcrToken"
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Action   = [
          "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        ]
        Resource = [
          "*",
        ]
      }
    ]
  })
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Changing to camelcase solved the problem.

Comment: if it worked for you, please upvote and mark it as approved. thanks